# Difference between str and getpass output

Tags: python, string

Okay it's been a little while since i last used Python so my knowledge is a bit rusty. I have a question regarding the getpass module and raw_input() and python strings in general.

I'm using the pycrypto module. There is a password string which is hashed using SHA256, the
digest of which is then used to decrypt an AES cipher.

The following code works:

```
password = "applesandpairsstairs"
print len(password)
print type(password)
plaintext = AESDecrypt(ciphertext, password, iv)
print "Plaintext: %s\n" % plaintext
```

I get the output:

```
20
<type 'str'>
Plaintext: This is some test data for use.
```

Obviously it's a bit silly having the password in the program so first I switched it out for raw_input().

```
password = raw_input("Enter Password: ")
print len(password)
print type(password)
plaintext = AESDecrypt(ciphertext, password, iv)
print "Plaintext: %s\n" % plaintext
```

When this prints it does:

```
20
<type 'str'>
Plaintext: (Load of ciphertext characters)
```

So it obviously doesn't work. Note i also tried an str() round the raw_input

Finally I have the code:

```
password = getpass.getpass("Enter Password: ",sys.stderr)
print len(password)
print type(password)
```

Which prints the same as the raw_input one.

AESDecrypt is a method that just calls the hash and decryption and returns the plaintext:

```
hash = SHA256.new()
hash.update(password)
key = hash.digest()
obj = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
plaintext = obj.decrypt(ciphertext)
return plaintext
```

Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Compare the `repr()` of the strings; matching length does not mean matching contents. `raw_input()` gives you normal strings, as you already discovered, so something else is wrong here.

Comment: When you say pycrypto, do you mean [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) package? If so, what is AESDecrypt?

Comment: @unutbu See the edited question for what AESDecrypt does.

Comment: Ah found the issue...i'm an idiot. I was typing the password in wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ah found the issue...i'm an idiot. I was typing the password in wrong.

Managed to miss it even with repeated prints of the password.